# pipreqs mysqlclient docker build issue

Tags: python, mysql, docker, build, mysql-python

I have a Dockerfile that contains the following...

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

...and I have a pip install command that reads from a requirements.txt file. The requirements.txt file contains the following [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) entry...

```
mysqlclient==2.1.1
```

When I build the Dockerfile, everything works as expected.

I also use [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) to keep my requirements.txt file updated with packages that only my application is currently using. If I run **pip list** I can see the following (and only database connector related package)...

```
mysqlclient        2.1.1
```

The problem is that when I run **pipreqs --force** to update the requirements.txt file, the mysqlclient entry gets replaced with the following [MySQL-python](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) entry...

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

When I next try to rebuild the docker file, it fails to build until I put the correct connector back into the requirements.txt file.

I can see that the **mysqlclient** project is a fork, and I'm therefore wondering if the project still contains an old reference?

Anyone else having the same issue or knows how to fix it?